# Is it possible to place around 500,000 overlays on google maps

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, dom, google-maps-api-3

I need to place around 500,000 objects on a map in structure like `<div><a><img>`.

But if I place only 2,000 objects as overlay my map crashes.

What can I do?

```
var srcImage = 'img/catalog-6.png';

var b = 1;
var a = 1;

var bounds = [10000];
var overlay = [10000]
var good;

for(i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
  bounds[i] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(b, b),
    new google.maps.LatLng(a, a));
  b = 1;
  a = 1;
  overlay = new firstpixel(bounds[i], srcImage, map);
  good++;
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: [Marker Clustering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering) looks like a possible option?

Comment: @Stu is it possible to make marker non-scalable like overlay?

Comment: You mean to disable zoom? Then it would just show the number of markers in each cluster, but that might not be what you want?

Comment: @Stu i need to place like 10x10 objects stick to eachother, and it should be fixed size on the map like overlay. Markers are scalable and have the same size on zooms steps.

Comment: ah I see, no I wouldn't know, perhaps someone with more experience with the API's might come along for you, gl!